# ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device instance during installing Google Assistant

Tags: python, windows, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

When installing Google Assistant at the last step before launching it using "python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk" give me this

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\moham\\AppData\\Roaming\\googlesamples-assistant\\device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [register your device](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/register-device) and include that parameter when you run the script.